# fread() operation replenish wrong data into structure

Tags: c, database, file, structure

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int roll;
    char subject[5];
    int mark;
}STUDENT;
```

I am using fwrite and fread to store above structure in the file.Now after storing student record in the file,I am modifying structure as below

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[10];

    char subject[5];
    int mark;
}STUDENT;
```

Now i am reading old record which i stored earlier in file.I am using fread() to do that.problem is data was not read properly from file in subject and mark data member of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you read the file. If you `fread` into the new struct use `sizeof(student)`, because "roll" is missing, the old roll value is read into `subject[5]` in the new structure. You can use `fscanf` to load the value into each field explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the file still contains the data in the old structure. It's a total of 10+(+2)+4+5+(+3)+3(+1)=28 bytes - values in brackets are struct padding.

When you do `fread` into a new struct from a file containing data in the old format, 4 bytes of `int roll;` will end up at the first 4 bytes of `char subject[5];`, while last 5th element of `subject` will be the first byte of the previous `subject`. Similar idea applies to `mark` field.

If you want to read and write structures like this - that is by doing a binary copy of it - you need to preserve the old format, even if it's no longer in use. A better idea is to use some kind of serialization library. Google's "Protocol Buffers" is just one of many examples of such libraries, which may give you an idea how this kind of problems are solved.

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide any reference to getting started with serialization library it will be great help.

Comment: @user5979363 In case of Protocol Buffers I've mentioned you can find a good tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial